# Removing Listview row on Button Click

Tags: android, listview

I have a Listview that gets fed questions and their corresponding choices as such:

[image]

The following constructor gets all the necessary information to feed the Listview. All string values are in Arraylists.

```
 public BaseQuestionAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<String> b, ArrayList<String> c, ArrayList<String> d, ArrayList<String> e) {
        activity = a;
        this.questionTitleArray = b;
        this.choicesArray = c;
        this.questionIdArray = d;
        this.userIdArray = e;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
```

Each row will hold a single question title and a variable number of choices. Dynamically created buttons will instantiate the choices and on each question title position the buttons will start generating. Like so, the following is the getView method in the BaseAdapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View vi = convertView;

vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.question_layout, null);

LinearLayout questionContainer = (LinearLayout) vi.findViewById(R.id.question_container);
LinearLayout choicesContainer = (LinearLayout) vi.findViewById(R.id.choices_container);

ViewGroup answersContainerParent = (ViewGroup) choicesContainer.getParent();
if (answersContainerParent != null)
    answersContainerParent.removeView(choicesContainer);

JSONArray choicesJSONArray = new JSONArray(choicesArray);

try {
    String bhb = choicesJSONArray.get(position).toString();
    jsnArray = new JSONArray(bhb);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

for (int answersArrayIterator = 0; answersArrayIterator < jsnArray.length(); answersArrayIterator++) {
    try {
        final Button choiceButton = new Button(activity);
        choiceButton.setId(buttonId);
        String questionId = questionIdArray.get(position).toString();

        choiceButton.setTag(questionId);
        choiceButton.setTag(position);

        ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) choiceButton.getParent();
        if (layout != null)
            layout.removeView(choiceButton);

        choiceButton.setText(jsnArray.get(answersArrayIterator).toString());
        choiceButton.setTextSize(16);
        choiceButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.question_button_template_style);
        choiceButton.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        choiceButton.setWidth(270);

        choiceButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                String choiceString = choiceButton.getText().toString();
                Object questionId = choiceButton.getTag();
                setDataToBeSent(userId, questionId, choiceString);

                Integer index = (Integer) v.getTag();
                System.out.println("SATURN ASCENDS: " + index);
                choicesArray.remove(index);
                notifyDataSetChanged();

                new HttpAsyncTask2().execute();

                return false;
            }
        });

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);

        choiceButton.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        choiceButton.setLayoutParams(params);

        buttonId++;
        choicesContainer.addView(choiceButton);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

TextView questionTitleET = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.question_title);
String questionTitle = questionTitleArray.get(position).toString();
questionTitleET.setText(questionTitle);

ViewGroup questionTitleETParent = (ViewGroup) questionTitleET.getParent();
if (questionTitleETParent != null)
questionTitleETParent.removeView(questionTitleET);

questionContainer.addView(questionTitleET);
questionContainer.addView(choicesContainer);

return vi;
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to remove the parent Listview row whenever a button is LonClicked. I'm trying to achieve this by setting an OnLongClickListener on every button created. Like so:

```
choiceButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    Integer index = (Integer) v.getTag();
    System.out.println("SATURN ASCENDS: " + index);
    choicesArray.remove(index);
    notifyDataSetChanged();

    return false;
}
});
```

Problem is that I don't know what to reference precisely in order for that to happen. Don't know whether its the choicesArray or any of the other resources I'm receiving. Currently when I long click on a button nothing happens. Any clue as to where I'm going wrong? Thank you.

Comment: *Problem is that I don't know what to reference precisely in order for that to happen.* - you need to reference the list on which the adapter is based. Without seeing your adapter's getCount() method I'm assuming that list is questionTitleArray.

Comment: @Luksprog But how can I reference the list in the BaseAdapter? The List is instantiated in another thread as the BaseAdapter is called and processed through an httpAsync call.

Comment: It doesn't matter where you create it. In order to change the adapter(removing a row) you need to change the list on which the adapter is based. I don't know at what reference are you thinking as you pass all lists to the adapter. Did you tried calling(inside the long click listener) on the list that you use in the getCount() method of the adapter?

Answer (score 0):

As Luksprog said on the comment, you need to remove the items from the container which is referenced in the getCount(). However I would also like to offer an improvement. Instead of using four different lists of Strings, use an Object which holds each of those string.

Eg.

```
public class MyClass {
    public String questionTitle;
    public String choice;
    public String questionId;
    public String userId;
}
```

After you have this class you can use a single list, which contains your object. This way you won't be confused as to which list items should be removed in order for the list to change.